# Nesting test runners

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am trying to find out whether and how it is possible to nest JUnit test runners, e.g. combine a [GuiceJUnitRunner](https://github.com/sfragis/GuiceJUnitRunner), a [Parameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) and a [HierarchicalcontextRunner](https://github.com/bechte/junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner/wiki).

To me, it seems that JUnit was not designed to achieve this easily, otherwise [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java#L15) should have a method which passes the next `Runner` as an argument.

Someone also implemented a [ParallelParameterized](https://junit-toolbox.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/googlecode/junittoolbox/ParallelParameterized.html) runner, which looks to me like combining `Parallel` and `Parameterized` was not easily possible.

When googling for "nested" and "JUnit", it comes up with lots of information for nested classes, but I'm looking for nesting `Runner`s, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called NestedRunner for running plain old Java classes in nested configuration.

your test starts with @RunWith(NestedRunner.class) and here is the example that I found:

```
@RunWith(NestedRunner.class)
public class ListTest {

    // inner class for sharing common context
    public class WithArrayList {
        // some context for these tests
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        public class WhenEmpty {
            @Test
            public void itIsEmpty() {
                assertTrue(list.isEmpty());
            }

            public class AfterAddingAnElement {
                // some more context for these tests
                String element = "Element";
                // you can use instance initializer to initialize your context
                // it will be run once per test
                {                            
                    // the list is still empty in here
                    assertTrue(list.isEmpty());
                    list.add(element);
                }

                @Test
                public void itIsNotEmpty() {
                    assertFalse(list.isEmpty());
                }

                @Test
                public void itContainsTheElement() {              
                    assertTrue(list.contains(element));
                }

                @Test
                public void addingAnotherElementIncreasesSize() {
                    int sizeBeforeAdding = list.size();
                    list.add("AnotherElement");
                    assertThat(list.size(), is(greaterThan(sizeBeforeAdding)));                        
                }

                @Test
                public void listSizeIsStillOne() {
                    assertThat(list.size(), is(equalTo(1)));
                }
            }

            @Test
            public void isStillEmpty() {
                assertTrue(list.isEmpty());              
            }
        }

        public class WithTwoElements {
            @Before
            public void init() {
                list.add("Element1");
                list.add("Element2");
            }

            @Test
            public void hasSizeOfTwo() {
                assertThat(list.size(), is(equalTo(2)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the [source](https://github.com/NitorCreations/CoreComponents/tree/master/junit-runners) for further info

Comment: This runner is for running tests in nested classes. It does not provide an option to apply many runners at the same time. The @RunWith annotation would need an addition like `@InnerRunners(GuiceJUnitRunner, ParameterizedRunner, HierarchicalcontextRunner)` to identify the nested runners. This is not available for the NestedRunner you linked to.